# Turn a sub into a sub with arguments

Tags: excel, vba

new to VBA and i have a bit of problems with a sub I wrote.

This sub takes values from various coloumns and put the values into a dictionary, then prints the dictionary in another coloumn.

```
Sub Unitario()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim bRiga As Long
    Dim aRiga As Long
    Dim cRiga As Long
    Dim dRiga As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim MyString As String
    Dim arr


Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'compare without distinction between capitals
'while vbBinaryCompare distinguish between capitals


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("c1").EntireColumn.Clear


aRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
bRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
cRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
dRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

For I = 4 To aRiga
    MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, "M")
    'to change coloumn i need to change values up there
    If Not Dict.exists(MyString) Then
        Dict.Add MyString, MyString
    End If
Next I
'adds coloumns value to dictionary

For I = 4 To bRiga
    MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, "N")
    'to change coloumn i need to change values up there
    If Not Dict.exists(MyString) Then
        Dict.Add MyString, MyString
    End If
Next I
    'adds coloumns value to dictionary

For I = 4 To cRiga
    MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, "O")
    'to change coloumn i need to change values up there
    If Not Dict.exists(MyString) Then
        Dict.Add MyString, MyString
    End If
Next I
'adds coloumns value to dictionary

    For I = 4 To dRiga
    MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, "P")
    'to change coloumn i need to change values up there
    If Not Dict.exists(MyString) Then
        Dict.Add MyString, MyString
    End If
Next I
'adds coloumns value to dictionary

arr = Dict.Items

Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("c1").Resize(Dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

it is clear that this sub is not optimized, since i have to manually change the values in the sub anytime i have to use it with other ranges.

what i'm trying to do is make a sub that can be called with various range arguments from buttons, without having to write 100 times the same macro with different ranges.
so that i could simply write something like this instead of manually modifying the code:

```
    Private sub Commandbutton1_Click
    Unitario(OutputSheet,OutputCell,InputRange1,InputRange2,..., InputRangeN)
    End Sub
```

so that i have only 1 macro on the excel and various buttons with different arguments.

can you help me?

Comment: Use **call** keyword to execute the sub.

Answer (score 2):

It can be like below:

`Sub Unitario(strFirstCol as String,strSecondCol as String, strThirdCol as String, strFourthCol as String)`

And then you will have to adopt the following section.

```
aRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, strFirstCol).End(xlUp).Row
bRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, strSecondCol).End(xlUp).Row
cRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, strThirdCol).End(xlUp).Row
dRiga = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(Rows.Count, strFourthCol).End(xlUp).Row
```

Inside each "For loop":

```
MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, strFirstCol)    '\\ Column M
MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, strSecondCol)   '\\ Column N
MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, strThirdCol)    '\\ Column O
MyString = Sheets("Lavoro").Cells(I, strFourthCol)   '\\ Column P
```

And then call the sub like

`Call Unitario("M","N","O","P")`

Answer (score 0):

whenever i have to add arguments to a often used sub, or function, i just add the arguments with ´optionaĺ.

This way i won ´t have to recode every call to the sub.

Example

```
Public sub test (byval optional addr as string)
```